# Create a class level decorator to automatically add a property

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, properties, python-decorators

I would like to create a class level decorator that automatically adds a property to an object, including the appropriate getter and setter methods and a backing variable. For example:

```
@autoproperty("foo", can_get=True, can_set=True, allow_null=False, default_value=0)
@autoproperty("baz", can_get=True, can_set=False, allow_null=True, default_value=0)
@autoproperty("bar")
class SomeNonTrivialClass(object):
   def __init__(self):
      #lots of stuff going on here

   def discombobulate(self):
      #this is obviously a very trivial example
      local_foo = self.foo;

      if (local_foo > 10):
         raise RuntimeError("Foo can never be more than 10")
      else:
         #do whatever with foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
   test = SomeNonTrivialClass()

   test.foo = 5
   test.discombobulate()
   test.foo = 11
   test.discombobulate()
```

I often find myself creating lots of "semi-complex" getters/setters (they could be done with just a simple property but they need default values and null protection. I would like to just be able to specify a decorator that does the heavy lifting of creating the properties on new instances of the class.

If I am way off base in this approach, I am open to an equally viable approach.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am working with python 3.X and python 2.7 so something that works in either is preferred but not necessary.

Update: I have added a bit more variety in what I am looking for. In general I need to be able to create a lot of these simple automatic properties (ala C# auto-property, but with a bit more flexibility). I do not necessarily want to expose the backing store, but I do want to make sure that an inspection of the instantiated object (not necessarily the class) shows the properties which have been created.

Comment: it sounds like you might want to write some [custom descriptors](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/05/23/python-faq-descriptors/).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Robᵩ my question is how to create a class level decorator that will automatically create the correct property on a class at instantiation.

Comment: @Eevee, Im fairly new to python, I can create the descriptor itself but I am having trouble figuring out how to wire it up so that when I create a new instance of the class I have the property available, with the right constraints on the created instance, not necessarily on the class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following class decorator would do that:

```
def autoproperty(name, can_get=True, can_set=True, allow_null=False, default_value=0):
    attribute_name = '_' + name
    def getter(self):
        return getattr(self, attribute_name, default_value)
    def setter(self, value):
        if not allow_null and value is None:
            raise ValueError('Cannot set {} to None'.format(name))
        setattr(self, attribute_name, value)

    prop = property(getter if can_get else None, setter if can_set else None)

    def decorator(cls):
        setattr(cls, name, prop)
        return cls

    return decorator
```

but you could just as well create a property factory:

```
def autoproperty(attribute_name, can_get=True, can_set=True, allow_null=False, default_value=0):
    def getter(self):
        return getattr(self, attribute_name, default_value)
    def setter(self, value):
        if not allow_null and value is None:
            raise ValueError('Cannot set {} to None'.format(name))
        setattr(self, attribute_name, value)
    return property(getter if can_get else None, setter if can_set else None)
```

then set that in the class with:

```
class SomeNonTrivialClass(object):
    # ...

    foo = autoproperty('_foo', can_get=True, can_set=True, allow_null=False, default_value=0)
```

The class decorator would make more sense if you needed to create *multiple* properties (perhaps with interdependencies) instead.

Comment: This is exactly what I need to do, I have a class who has maybe a dozen properties that need to be configured on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more direct approach, which avoids decorating the class.

```
class SomeNonTrivialClass(object):
   def __init__(self):
      #lots of stuff going on here

   foo = autoproperty("foo", can_get=True, can_set=True, allow_null=False, default_value=0)

   def discombobulate(self):
      #this is obviously a very trivial example
      local_foo = self.foo;

class autoproperty(property):
    def __init__(self, name, can_get, can_set, allow_null, default_value):
        ...
```

Comment: This seems like a NameError to me (since autoproperty isn't defined when you try to create the class).  Otherwise, a good suggestion as far as I can see ...

Comment: @mgilson : no NameError if you create instances after both classes body.

Comment: Part of why I need to decorate the class is that I dont necessarily know at design time what properties are needed. They are created from a prototyping factory facility, where the autoproperties are added afterwards.